# Datatables not displaying Django

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, datatables, typeerror

I have datatables set up according to how it explains on the site

This is my base.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
{% load static %}
<head>
    <link href="{% static 'tickets/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" >
    <link href="{% static 'tickets/css/styles.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'tickets/DataTables-1.10.8/media/css/jquery.dataTables.css'  %}">

    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{% static  'tickets/DataTables-1.10.8/media/js/jquery.js' %}"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src"{% static 'tickets/Datatables-1.10.8/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>

<title>{% block title %}VGTSI Tickets {% endblock %} </title>

<script type="text/javascript" class="init">

    $(document).ready( function ($) {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();

    });


</script>

</head>
```

This is the table for datatables

```
<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Title</th><th>Date</th><th>Open/Closed</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {% for ticket in ticket_list %}
    <tr>
        <td><a href="{% url 'tickets:view_ticket' ticket.id %}">{{ticket.title}}</a></td>   
        <td>{{ticket.dateOfIssue}}</td>              
        <td>{{ticket.resolved}}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
    </tbody>
</table>
```

And the view

```
@login_required
def view_all(request):
    ticket_list = Ticket.objects.order_by('dateOfIssue')[:20]
    context = {'ticket_list' : ticket_list}
    return render(request, 'tickets/view_all.html', context)
```

After looking in the console on firebug the error I get is TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
I've looked at other questions on this site with similar problems but none of their solutions have worked. 
Is it something obvious? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing an equal sign (`=`) in this line (right after `src`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src"{% static 'tickets/Datatables-1.10.8/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
```

Fixed:

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="{% static 'tickets/Datatables-1.10.8/media/js/jquery.dataTables.js' %}"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you! Something so small I didn't notice it